# Merge TFS Projects and retaining history

Tags: version-control, tfs

We currently have one TFS project per application which makes it difficult to manage. Moreover, many of the programs are closely related to each other and share code and Work Items. Because of this, I was thinking to move everything to one single large TFS project.

My question is HOW do I do to merge all TFS projects to the same project and retaining the history and Work Items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use `TFS Integration Platform` in order to merge your datas.

link : http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/

You have another solution based on export datas to flat file with `Excel Add In`  and `WIQL query`, and secondly import theses files to your new project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately it yet does not work with TFS 2013. I'll just have to wait until there is an update :-(

Comment: happy to help you magol

Comment: If I choose to use your other suggestions with Excel Add In and WIQL query, how do I do? What should I do to copy the source code while maintaining history?

Comment: Excel is used just for WIs.

Comment: I understand that. But we do not use WIs so much, so it's not really that important. So actually, my question is if I can I copy the source code and keep the history.

Comment: with Add in Excel you can't export source code, WIQl it's not used for source code

Comment: I think I misunderstood you.
You wrote that Add in Excel and WIQl was an alternative to TFS Integration Platform to make the migration, so I thought that was a feasible way to perform the migration. But with this method, I'm not migrate any history of the source code.